# Android googleMap v2 Failed to contact google servers

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, android-maps-v2, android-maps

So I have this problem with GoogleMaps v2 in Android, I'm always getting

> 06-02 17:06:56.460: I/Google Maps Android API(20121): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
>
> 06-02 17:07:11.785: E/Google Maps Android API(20121): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).

Now I have checked for WIFI state and I have the "READ_GSERVICES" permission, already tried to clear the app data and even reinstall it, Got my SHA1 again and created a new key, I tried with a debug and a release.

Here is my Manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<permission
    android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" >
</uses-feature>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:name="com.example.test.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY" />
</application>
```

Comment: I have flagged this for deletion because the guy's API key is still visible in the edit history. This question should be deleted by Tal Hindi and re-entered without the API Key.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` permission is repeated. Delete one of the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate the `Google Maps Android API v2` service in your Google Developers Console, in the Menu `APIs & auth`. 
Set it to ON. After making that change, uninstall your app and reinstall it so the changes will take effect.